# Certain keys on built-in keyboard do not generate scancodes

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-22.04, scancodes

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad P40, which is pretty much the same as the Yoga460 as far as I know.

My problem is the following: The built-in german layout keyboard used to work just fine until I have added a new keyboard layout via settings and used an external keyboard for some time. Now when I run `showkey --scancode` or `xev | grep keycode` certain keys on the built-in keyboard do not generate any scancodes, while all working keys generate double scancodes in the terminal. In my opinion this sounds like a hardware issue. Can anyone, who is more of an expert than me, maybe confirm this?

Tried to change the keyboard settings and fiddled a bit with the keyboard mappings, but so far no success.